# Proguard obfuscation impact on .apk size

Tags: android, open-source, proguard, obfuscation

I'm developing an open source (ASL2.0) application for android: https://github.com/Centril/sleepfighter/tree/librarize

Therefore there's no need from a security standpoint to obfuscate the code.
But I'm wondering if there could be some benefits in terms of reducing the size of the .apk archive.

I tested this myself and got a reduction from ~2650 KB to 2335 KB when not using and using obfuscation respectively... what are your experiences?

Should I obfuscate the releases even tho this is an open source app for the sake of reducing .apk size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument *for* proguard in this case is to optimize the code. Obviousily mileage will vary, but Proguard will attempt to inline and collapse what it can. Theoretically this could improve the apps performance.

With respect to size - the majority of your APK footprint is likely caused my resources such as images, rather than code. So Proguard won't be able to help much there, as it seems you've already found.

Some arguments *against* Proguard would be:

1. it could introduce bugs, such as stripping away classes that it shouldn't have.
2. Makes it slightly harder to interpret stack traces, in the case where you're collecting crash information - you need keep a translation file.
3. It's one more thing that could break your build process and serve as a barrier to entry toward people contributing to the project.

Comment: whoever downvoted, let me know how I can improve the answer please :)

Comment: Wasn't me ;) How important do you reckon collecting crash info is on release builds?

Also: the size reduction is probably overstated in my example, since I didn't provide instructions for proguard to not obfuscate vital classes - I haven't verified that the app actually works with obfuscation yet.

Using optimization for android apps is tricky - Dalvik doesn't like it much. Maybe this will change when ART becomes more widespread.

Comment: Do you have any other tips for reducing .apk size, btw? I'll give you +1 for any more answers you have ;)

Comment: IMO collecting crash info is even more important for a release build than it is for a development build. No better way to test Murphy's law than to get it in the hands of thousands of devices in different conditions.

Comment: Cheers - I'll mark your answer as accepted if no one else has a go at it in a while ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are no definitive answers, but in my experiments:

- The size of classes.dex is typically reduced by 30-90%. This mostly depends on the number and size of the project libraries. If large parts those libraries are unused, ProGuard can remove them. Scala applications tend top be the most extreme examples, with their large Scala runtime library.
- The size of the final .apk file is typically reduced by 4-70%, as a result. This mostly depends on the size of the resources and assets, which ProGuard leaves untouched.

With optimization enabled, the performance of applications is improved by up to 20% for computationally intensive applications (in Dalvik bytecode).

In the ART environment, a smaller code base can speed up the pre-compilation after the app has been downloaded to the device. Moreover, ProGuard can still improve the performance by up to 30% for ART. Apparently, the optimizations of ProGuard and ART are still largely complementary.

Sam is correct in his answer about potential downsides. You start from perfectly working code (hopefully), so any additional processing steps introduce some effort and risk. If size and performance are your main goals, you can disable obfuscation (-dontobfuscate), so the stack traces remain readable.

You can find some more details about ProGuard for Android in my [presentations](http://www.saikoa.com/tags/proguard) for Droidcon and other conferences.

(I am the developer of ProGuard)